# Is there a coding standards enforcement tool for Scala?

Tags: scala, coding-style, checkstyle

Where I work, we use mostly Java. We've always made extensive use of [CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) to enforce our coding standards for Java.

We're now branching out into Scala. Many of the same considerations as in Java apply (indentation/whitespace, naming conventions, ...) - and arguably having a consistent coding style is even more important given the power of the language.

However, there does not seem to be a Checkstyle equivalent for Scala.

Does anyone know of one?

Comment: I like the term "coding standards enforcement tool". Sounds like a torture device. :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes. It is called [Scalastyle](http://www.scalastyle.org/). (Same sort of focus as Checkstyle and findbugs). It's currently in version 0.2.0, we're adding rules all of the time

EDIT (Dec 2012):

Scalastyle 0.2.0 was released last month, with a total of 46 rules. There is, in no particular order:

- A maven plugin
- An eclipse plugin
- An SBT plugin

Under development are:

- An Intellij plugin
- A sonar plugin

Contributions/bug fixes are always welcome: [github](https://github.com/scalastyle/scalastyle).

Comment: That's just what I wanted to hear, thanks. Will aim to get involved.

Answer (score 7):

For code formatting, you can use [Scalariform](https://github.com/mdr/scalariform).

It can be used standalone, integrated into an editor, or as an [SBT plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbtscalariform) that runs it automatically before every compilation.

Comment: That looks useful, but I'm wary of having a tool carry out too much automatic mangling of my code.

Answer (score 4):

[Codacy](http://www.codacy.com) integrates [Scalastyle](http://www.scalastyle.org/) (amazing work from Matthew) along with custom rules (like checking for `Option.get()` and warning you when you do them) and works as an improved Sonar for Scala.
Free for open source.

You also have [abide](https://github.com/scala/scala-abide) from the Typesafe team and [scapegoat](https://github.com/sksamuel/scalac-scapegoat-plugin) from the makers of SCoverage.

Answer (score 3):

There's [sniff](https://github.com/arosien/sniff), which detect "code smells" based on regular expressions. It can be used as a [Specs2](http://specs2.org/) test, which is nice.